# e1071 svm predict output seem to have wrong class ("numeric" instead of "factor")

Tags: r, svm

If I use the example code from the [e1071 documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf) on page 52, I obtain a `pred` variable of class "factor".

```
> str(pred)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:150] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

This is fine; but when I use the same commands on my data, I obtain a pred variable of class "numeric":

```
> str(pred)
 Named num [1:1000] 0.95 0.0502 0.05 0.9902 -0.0448 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:1000] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

and this seems wrong; the prediction does not seem to work at all.

My code is:

```
# create variables to store the path to the files you downloaded:
data.dir   <- "c:/kaggle/scikit/"
train.file <- paste0(data.dir, 'train.csv')
trainLabels.file <- paste0(data.dir, 'trainLabels.csv')


# READ DATA - CAREFUL IF THERE IS A HEADER OR NOT
train <- read.csv(train.file, stringsAsFactors=F, header=FALSE)
trainLabels <- read.csv(trainLabels.file, stringsAsFactors=F, header=FALSE)


# LOADING LIBRARY e1071
install.packages('e1071') 
library('e1071')


## classification mode
model <- svm(train, trainLabels)

summary(model)

# test with train data
pred <- predict(model, train)
```

Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that my classes were given as a data.frame instead of a factor.

I fixed it thanks to this other question on [converting a data.frame to a factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274454/convert-one-column-data-frame-into-factor/19274534?noredirect=1#19274534).

So my working code is:

```
data.dir   <- "c:/xampp/htdocs/Big Data/kaggle/scikit/"
train.file <- paste0(data.dir, 'train.csv')
trainLabels.file <- paste0(data.dir, 'trainLabels.csv')


# READ DATA - CAREFUL IF THERE IS A HEADER OR NOT
train <- read.csv(train.file, stringsAsFactors=F, header=FALSE)
trainLabels <- read.csv(trainLabels.file, stringsAsFactors=F, header=FALSE)

# Make the trainLabels a factor
trainLabels <- as.factor(trainLabels$V1)


# APPLYING SVM TO KAGGLE DATA
install.packages('e1071') 
library('e1071')


## classification mode
model <- svm(train, trainLabels)

summary(model)

# test with train data
pred <- predict(model, train)

# Check accuracy:
table(pred, trainLabels)
```