# Convert one column data.frame into factor

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame:

```
> str(trainLabels)
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: int  1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 ...
```

I wish to obtain a factor as follows:

```
> str(trainLabels)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 ...
```

I have tried:

```
trainLabels$V1 <- as.factor(trainLabels$V1)
```

but that doesn't seem to work; it does change the structure, but it's still not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reassigning back into the data.frame column,

```
trainLabels <- as.factor(trainLabels$V1)
```

Note that in your requirements, the original `trainLabels` is a `data.frame` whereas the final output is a vector.  They are two completely different objects being assigned to the same name, the latter overwriting the former.

Comment: Using factor() instead of as.factor() will keep any names that were present in the V1 column.

Comment: and with `factor()` you can control the factor levels with the `levels` argument, which is useful if the data does not contain all desired factors.